# Render to Html with appropriate values in django

Tags: python, django

I having a dictionary

```
a = {'name': u'45445454',
     'tracks': [{'A_TITLE': u'abb',
             'IS': u'144',
             'PN': u'3',
             'T_TITLE': u'123'},
            {'A_TITLE': u'abb',
             'IS': u'45454454',
             'PN': u'3',
             'T_TITLE': u'225'},
            {'A_TITLE': u'ggg',
             'IS': u'232',
             'PN': u'000',
             'T_TITLE': u'555'}]}

<table>

{% for e in tracks %}
<tr> <td> Title </td> <td> {{ e.A_TITLE }}  -  PN {{ e.PN }}</td></tr>
<tr> <td> Name </td><td> {{e.T_TITLE }} - IS {{e.IS }} </td></tr>
   {% endfor %}

</table>
```

Now it was printing like

```
 <tr> <td>TITLE </td><td> abb - PN 3 </td></tr>
 <tr> <td>NAME </td><td> 123 - IS 144 </td></tr>
 <tr> <td>TITLE </td><td> abb - PN 3 </td></tr>
 <tr> <td>NAME </td><td> 225 - IS 45454454 </td></tr>
 <tr> <td>TITLE </td><td> ggg - PN 000 </td></tr>
 <tr> <td>NAME </td><td> 555 - IS 232 </td></tr>
```

Note:  A_TITLE is depends on PN
I want it arrange by A_TITLE.

Like

```
 <tr> <td>TITLE </td><td> abb - PN 3 </td></tr>
 <tr> <td>NAME </td><td> 123 - IS 144 </td></tr>
 <tr> <td>NAME </td><td> 225 - IS 45454454 </td></tr>
 <tr> <td>TITLE </td><td> ggg - PN 000 </td></tr>
 <tr> <td>NAME </td><td> 555 - IS 232 </td></tr>
```

I am struggling in this a more time ,

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think you want to group the for/loop with `A_TITLE`? use `regroup`

Comment: look at Django templates builtin [**regroup**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

Comment: @Anzel Could you please post your answer related with my senario

Comment: Just look at @catavaran's even better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the combination of the [`dictsort`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsort) filter and [`{% ifchanged %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) template tag:

```
{% for e in tracks|dictsort:"A_TITLE" %}

    {% ifchanged %}
        <tr><td>Title</td><td>{{ e.A_TITLE }}  -  PN {{ e.PN }}</td></tr>
    {% endifchanged %}

    <tr><td>Name</td><td>{{e.T_TITLE }} - IS {{e.IS }}</td></tr>

{% endfor %}
```